# Upload xls, add some calculations and show results in Dash

Tags: python, pandas, flask, plotly-dash

I'm trying to do some operations with my Flask app using Plotly Dash.

Basically i would like to :

- upload a xls file into my dash app
- Add some trasformations/ calculations on pre-loaded xls
- Show the results (as a Datatable)

This is my reproducible code.
I 'can't show the results as Datatable after loading xls file.

Thanks

```
import io
import datetime
import base64
import pandas as pd
import dash_table as dt
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from flask import Flask

FA = "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css"

server = Flask(__name__)

app = dash.Dash(
                name=__name__,
                server=server,
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, FA],
                suppress_callback_exceptions=True
                )

# file upload function
def parse_contents(contents, filename):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
        elif 'xlsx' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None
    return df


# callback table creation
@app.callback(Output('table', 'data'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
               Input('upload-data', 'filename')])
def update_output(contents, filename):
    if contents is not None:
        df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
        # add some operations/calculations and show results
        if df is not None:
            return df.to_dict('records')
        else:
            return [{}]
    else:
        return [{}]


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H5("Upload Files"),
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        multiple=False),
    html.Br(),
    html.H5("Updated Table"),
    html.Div(dt.DataTable(data=[], id='table'))

    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(port=8888)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're not setting the `columns` property of the `DataTable` component.

You could set it by changing your `update_output` callback to something like this:

```
@app.callback(
    [Output("table", "data"), Output("table", "columns")],
    [Input("upload-data", "contents"), Input("upload-data", "filename")],
)
def update_output(contents, filename):
    if contents is not None:
        df = parse_contents(contents, filename)
        # add some operations/calculations and show results
        if df is not None:
            return df.to_dict("records"), [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns]
        else:
            return [{}], []
    else:
        return [{}], []
```

https://dash.plotly.com/datatable

*Also you might already have done this, but for making xlsx work I had to install openpyxl.*